# 締結 can this be translated as "engagement" in the context of mechanical clutch connection?

Tags: translation, word-choice, meaning

According to weblio, the main translations of 締結 are "conclusion," "fastening," and "cerclage". With Google translate, "entered into," "conclusion," and "contract" come up.

I've run several different searches but have not been able to come up with "engagement" as a translation for 締結.

However, when I run searches for "クラッチの締結” I am finding this phrase translated as "engagement of the clutch" or "clutch engagement."

I am assuming that in the specific context of referring to a connection of a clutch, the word 締結 can be translated as "engagement," but would appreciate confirmation and/or suggestions for a better translation. Thanks!

Comment: I can't help much but 締結 means (条約・約束を取り結ぶこと (大辞林)) so it seems more about a binding between two moral entities. After I don't know and it may be some jargon in your field. After all you may see 締結 as 締めて結ぶこと.

Comment: You are likely getting that translation because of the の. The engine is just using literal translations of what's on either side. Having said that. maybe an implementation of 実行(jikkou) used when something begin to run or move, mostly for mechanical stuff or computers. クラッチ実行瞬間（moment the clutch runs).

Comment: maybe even just 動く、as that is used to describe an engine when it starts.

Comment: 締結 can this be translated as “engagement” in the context of mechanical clutch connection? -------> Yes !　　「ねじ（の）締結」 も言うようだ。　　　思い出したのは「ピストン周りが磨耗して鏡面状」の質問と、あと、「締結」 みたいな語彙が機械工学の用語でもあったんだ！　という質問で、この後者が思い出せん。　もう歳か？

Answer (score 5):

In machine engineering, 締結 commonly translates to [*fastening*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastener), and 締結具 translates to *fastener*. (Note that ファスナー in Japanese usually refers to a zipper.)

締結 is probably not the most common word for *engagement* in the specific context of clutches. Japanese Wikipedia does not use 締結 at all on the article about [クラッチ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%83%81) but they basically use 接続, a much easier word meaning *connection*. [Japanese Industrial Standards B0152 Clutches and brakes－Vocabulary](http://kikakurui.com/b0/B0152-1997-01.html) does not use 締結 at all, but defines 係合 as engagement (including slippery ones) and 連結 as interlocking (i.e., non-slippery). [This glossary](http://www.oguraclutch.co.jp/product/helpful/term/sadou.html) translates 連結 as engaging but says nothing about 締結, either. On the other hand, some technical articles about clutches do use 締結 often, and they seem to mean engagement in general, including slippery ones.

So you can probably translate 締結 as *engagement*, but please make sure how it is used in the article you are translating. If 締結 refers to only non-slippery engagement in your article, *interlocking* may be the better translation.